# Why a MIPS pipeline has a memory read signal, but not a register read signal?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

I'd like to know why we need a memory read signal when reading from memory? I get why we need a memory write for the same reason that we want a register write signal.

But we don't need a register-read signal, so why do we need a memory-read signal?

Comment: Is there a programming context for this question, or is this hardware-related?

Comment: This is hardware-related. I was talking about the MIPS single cycle and multi cycle implementation. I should have mentioned this, so I do apologize. Basically, what I want to know is why we need a control signal for memory read when we don't need one for register reading. Thanks!

Comment: Because your CPU core is not the only thing on a bus that may want to access the memory. There must be an arbiter (or any other bus-managing device) that'd look at this "want to read" signal and schedule who should be granted a right to read or write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to tell it when to write, but not when to read, it would have to read all the time whenever write is not asserted.

If you make the processor perform a memory read when there's no actual read operation to do, should it do a random read and pollute the cache, and also potentially reading a faulting address?

So, the read signal is there to prevent an invalid or inappropriate memory read operation.

By contrast, the register read is simply always done even when not required by some instructions — the difference is that there are no negative consequences for doing that as those unwanted reads are simply ignored (and there's no concept of faulting or cache pollution there).

(At worst, maybe some power is lost doing those reads, but that hardware is there and powered even if not used, so we would need some advanced hardware power saving techniques to take advantage of that, especially as randomly as would be required for an instruction stream.)

Still, if you wanted a register read signal you could put one in, just that it isn't necessary given the read will be ignored by later control signals for downstream MUXes anyway.

Comment: To save power, you'd just be gating some logic so fewer transistors are switching, not trying to actually cut the supply voltage or put anything into a "sleep state".  e.g. when register read wasn't asserted, block propagation of any reg-number signal into that (register file) SRAM read port so those lines all stay in the same state they were previously.  (And/or gate the clock signal to things like flip-flops for the output?)

Comment: This takes extra transistors just to save power, and wouldn't be worth spending transistors on in early MIPS designs.  ([When power density wasn't a problem](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) because each transistor took up so much space, and clock frequencies were lower.)  Instead you'd just want to get the job done with as few gates as possible, as you say letting them switch based on garbage inputs as long as the result was safely ignored and it wasn't going to assert a stall or fault signal.  (cache miss or TLB miss)